# Multithreaded console application that runs as windows service (using Topshelf)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console-application, worker

I am trying to create a windows service which monitors a folder periodically and if there are new files inside, it can trigger a PowerShell script for it (script can handle the rest of work for each event)

So far I have created a C# console application which is using TopShelf (for easy debugging and run it as a service) but it can only do one action.

What I am looking for if one event occurs it triggers the script and let it run until complete (or it fails) but meanwhile there is another event during the loop run in that folder it should be able to spawn another thread to run another copy of that script

```
while(True):
if file exist:
   Run "Script.ps1"
```

but I want something like if after loop iteration it finds more than one files then it spawns a separate threads for each file processing further.

```
while(True):
if file exist:
thread1 -> run script.ps1 (for 1st file)
thread2 -> run script.ps1 (for 2nd file)
.
.
.
threadn -> run script.ps1 (for nth file)
```

n number of files n number of threads ( a limit can be enforced eg.10)

So far I have created a class but all it does if only one job.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace Packaging
{
    public class Fileextractor
    {
        private readonly Timer _timer;

        public Fileextractor()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(5000) { AutoReset = true };
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

        }

        private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
           // find file in folder
           // if file exist
              // run script.ps1

        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _timer.Start();

        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you are asking help with. If you just want to spin off a new thread that's easy. Just use [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem?view=net-5.0):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
   // your code that will run on a separate thread here
});
```

Comment: Can I integrate it with my existing code ?